# Query to fetch Currency (USD) from Key field in JSON data stored in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

I need to get the account balance based on currency (e.g only USD) from the given JSON doc stored in couchDB

Tried with regex (regular expression) but that is applicable for Value not key data.

{
  "_id": "ID_000000000",
  "_rev": "45-0ffa69047a93df6fe71656f5a7aa8681",
  "recordID": "32123",
  "currencyData": {
    "1000104183USD": 100,
    "9000282526INR": 300,
    "2340282526GBP": 0
  },
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "~version": "3213"
}

Need a filter or query which will give me data based on currency either USD, INR or GBP

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a view:

```
function (doc) {
  for (var cur in doc.currencyData) {
    if (doc.currencyData.hasOwnProperty(cur)) {
      emit([doc._id, cur], 1)
    }
  }
}
```

The view can then be filtered with start_key & end_key to pick the dataset and currency that you need.

**Without filter:**
`GET /yourDB/_design/myView/_view/byCurrency`

[image]

**Filtered for USD:**
`GET /yourDB/_design/myView/_view/byCurrency?start_key=["ID_000000000","1000104183USD"%20]&end_key=["ID_000000000",%20"1000104183USD"]`
[image]

Comment: Hi Jay, Thanks for your reply. Need little more help from you. The data (1000104183USD) is a combination of account number and currency code. Here 1000104183 is an account number. and USD is currency code. Account number is dynamic and I need JSON result for USD currency code and I cannot use account number as end key as you show.

Comment: To seperate the accountnumber from the currency you can use Javascripst substring function.

var accountCurrency = "1000104183USD"
var currency = accountCurrency.substr(-3)
// result "USD"
var accountNo = accountCurrency.substr(accountCurrency.length - 3)
// result: "1000104183"

In your view you can now emit the accountNo and the Currency as keys
Combined with a reduce function you can then sum the accounts

Comment: Once again thank you Jay for your prompt comment. I cannot use javascript. The implementation is using Hyperledger Blockchain and couchDB. I need to filter it using regular expression or whatever needs to be done in Couchdb side. I tried this["{\"selector\": { \"currencyEntry\": { \"$regex\": \"*USD$\"} } }"] but it is application for Value side not Key side.

Comment: Couchdb views are written in Javascript. Do you have access to the database to create views or can you just read? Without creating a view or processing the data in some kind of external programm you can't achiev what you want. Couchdb just lets you query data by the _id field and there just from the beginning.

Comment: If you can just read the database and not create design docs / view then you can't use my answer. In this case you would need to download entire data and then process it in an other program.

Please update your question or create a new one where you specify that you do have only read access to the database. Please specify also what technology stack you are able to use.